# cakePHP get a variable from each Model and Controller

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1

I got a question. I have a db table with settings (id, name).
If I read them from the db

```
$settings = $this->Setting->find('list');
```

How can I do this in the AppController or something like that to access from each Controller and Model?

Hope someone can help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Explanation:**

I would assume you're looking for something like below (Obviously you'll want to tweak it per your own application, but - it's the idea).

In the app controller, it

- finds the settings from the table
- repeats through each and puts each one into a "Configure" variable

**Code:**

```
/**
 * Read settings from DB and populate them in constants
 */
function fetchSettings(){
    $this->loadModel('Setting');
    $settings = $this->Setting->findAll();

    foreach($settings as $settingsData) {
        $value = $settingsData['Setting']['default_value'];

        //note: can't check for !empty because some values are 0 (zero)
        if(isset($settingsData['Setting']['value']) 
            && $settingsData['Setting']['value'] !== null
            && $settingsData['Setting']['value'] !== '') {
            $value = $settingsData['Setting']['value'];
        }
        Configure::write($settingsData['Setting']['key'], $value);
   }
}
```

Then, you can access them anywhere in your app via `Configure::read('myVar');`

**A warning from the CakePHP book** about Configure variables.  (I think they're fine to use in this case, but - something to keep in mind):

> CakePHP’s Configure class can be used to store and retrieve
>   application or runtime specific values. Be careful, this class allows
>   you to store anything in it, then use it in any other part of your
>   code: a sure temptation to break the MVC pattern CakePHP was designed
>   for. The main goal of Configure class is to keep centralized variables
>   that can be shared between many objects. Remember to try to live by
>   “convention over configuration” and you won’t end up breaking the MVC
>   structure we’ve set in place.